# Ant Design error: "Form.create() getFieldDecorator is not a function"

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs, antd

```
"antd": "^1.11.1",
"react": "^15.1.0",
"react-dom": "^15.1.0",
```

**Error: Uncaught TypeError: getFieldDecorator is not a function**

ant design demo: https://ant.design/components/form/

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Form, Icon, Input, Button } from 'antd';
const FormItem = Form.Item;

const HorizontalLoginForm = Form.create()(React.createClass({
  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.form.validateFields((err, values) => {
      if (!err) {
        console.log('Received values of form: ', values);
      }
    });
  },
  render() {
    const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form;
    return (
      <Form inline onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <FormItem>
          {getFieldDecorator('userName', {
            rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please input your username!' }],
          })(
            <Input addonBefore={<Icon type="user" />} placeholder="Username" />
          )}
        </FormItem>
        <FormItem>
          {getFieldDecorator('password', {
            rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please input your Password!' }],
          })(
            <Input addonBefore={<Icon type="lock" />} type="password" placeholder="Password" />
          )}
        </FormItem>
        <FormItem>
          <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">Log in</Button>
        </FormItem>
      </Form>
    );
  },
}));

export default HorizontalLoginForm;
```

Answer (score 4):

[.getFieldDecorator()](https://ant.design/components/form/#this.props.form.getFieldDecorator(id,-options)) is introduced in antd@2.0

You can find 1.x docs here http://1x.ant.design

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import 'antd/dist/antd.css'
import { Form, Input, Tooltip, Icon, Cascader, Select, Row, Col, Checkbox, Button, AutoComplete, } from 'antd'
const FormItem = Form.Item

class LoginForm extends React.Component {
  state = {
    confirmDirty: false,
    autoCompleteResult: [],
  }

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.props.form.validateFieldsAndScroll((err, values) => {
      if (!err) {
        console.log('Received values of form: ', values)
      }
    })
  }

  render() {
    const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form

    return (
      <Form inline onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <FormItem>
          {getFieldDecorator('userName', {
            rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please input your username!' }],
          })(
            <Input addonBefore={<Icon type="user" />} placeholder="Username" />
          )}
        </FormItem>
        <FormItem>
          {getFieldDecorator('password', {
            rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please input your Password!' }],
          })(
            <Input
              addonBefore={<Icon type="lock" />}
              type="password"
              placeholder="Password"
            />
          )}
        </FormItem>
        <FormItem>
          <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
            Log in
          </Button>
        </FormItem>
      </Form>
    )
  }
}

const HorizontalLoginForm = Form.create({ name: 'login' })(LoginForm)

export default HorizontalLoginForm
```